# How to convert unicode column data to readable text in mySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
+-----+--------+------------------------------------------+------+
| PID | cat_id |               product_name               | unit |
+-----+--------+------------------------------------------+------+
|  19 |      1 | &#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84 | KG   |
+-----+--------+------------------------------------------+------+
```

i need to view the original text from this Unicode in select query,this Unicode includes English and other languages.

Comment: @jarlh  column data type varchar

Answer (score 0):

The following only works on the provided example but I imagine you can adapt it as required:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',2),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',3),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',4),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',5),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',6),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',7),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',8),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',9),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',10),2)),
    CHAR(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('&#67&#65&#83&#72&#69&#87&#32&#78&#85&#84','&#',11),2))
    );
```

Result = CASHEW NUT

Comment: Perhaps as a stored procedure, with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store text as HTML codes in the first place? This is a very bad idea, when you are actually interested in the real text. You should change this or decide not to be interested in the *meaning* of the string's content, i.e. simply store these string codes, but only interpret them *outside* the database.

However, it *is* possible to have MySQL do the conversion. You need a function for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION decode_string(encoded_string TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE decoded_string TEXT DEFAULT ''; -- the target string
  DECLARE ucodestr TEXT DEFAULT ''; -- a code taken from the source string
  DECLARE strlen INT; -- the length of the string to scan
  DECLARE strpos INT DEFAULT 1; -- the position in the string to scan
  DECLARE chr TEXT; -- a character from the string to scan

  -- Convert the encoded string from '&#67&#65&#83' to '67;65;83;' so every code is followed by a semicolon.
  SET encoded_string = REPLACE(CONCAT(SUBSTR(encoded_string, 3), '&#'), '&#', ';');
  SET strlen = length(encoded_string);

  chrloop: WHILE strpos <= strlen DO
    SET chr = substr(encoded_string, strpos, 1);

    IF  chr = ';' THEN
      -- Convert the found code to its unicode character and add this to the output encoded_string.
      SET decoded_string = CONCAT(decoded_string, CHAR(ucodestr USING ucs2));
      SET ucodestr = '';
    ELSE
      -- Build the string to hold the complete code number digit by digit.
      SET ucodestr = CONCAT(ucodestr, chr);
    END IF;

    SET strpos = strpos + 1;
   END WHILE chrloop;

  RETURN decoded_string;
END;
/
```

Then use this function in SQL, e.g.:

```
select decode_string(product_name) as txt
from unicodes_table;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4afd/1.